# JPA mapping issue when mapping two entities with same `JoinColumn`

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm having some weird situation, where I have for example an entity called **Article**, which has a relation to **Supplier**, but also to **Supplier Contact Person**. For example:

[image: ERD]

Supplier is linked to Article by Supplier_Id, while ContactpersonSupplier is linked to Article by both Supplier_Id (to SupplierId) and Supplier_Contactperson_Id (to Id).

So, right now we mapped all relations on `Article`:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "Supplier_Id")
private Supplier supplier;

@JoinColumns({
  @JoinColumn(name = "Supplier_Id"),
  @JoinColumn(name = "Supplier_Contactperson_Id")
private SupplierContactperson supplierContactperson;
```

This does not work because we're mapping **Supplier_Id** twice, once for `supplier` and once for `supplierContactperson`. If you do this, you get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: Article column: Supplier_Id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

In a normal situation you would link them up like this: `Article` -> `ContactpersonSupplier` -> `Supplier`, and then there would be no problems.

However, `ContactpersonSupplier` is not required, but `Supplier` is required. This means that if we leave the contactperson away, we can't provide a supplier.

We cannot use `insertable = false, updatable = false` for the very same reason, if we put these values on `supplier`, we cannot add a supplier if the contactperson is not provided.
We cannot add them on `supplierContactperson` either, because JPA/Hibernate requires you to put it on all `@JoinColumn`'s inside a `@JoinColumns`, and if we do that, we can't save a contactperson.

One idea we have is to simply map the IDs, in stead of using related entities, but we're wondering if there's an alternative approach that might work. So the question is, how should we solve this mapping issue?

*One thing to mention though, the data structure cannot be changed.*

Comment: Rather than state "this does not work", provide the exact error message you get please. Also if I look at the schematic, I would get the idea the contactpersonsupplier has its own unique ID and Article.supplier_contact_person maps directly to it.

Comment: @Gimby I thought that the error was described pretty well by the next part of my question (that Hibernate throws a mapping exception and says you have to put `insert=false` and `update=false` on one of both joins because you can't have it mapped twice). Anyways, I described the relations between my tables a bit more and provided the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this worked for me:

```
 @JoinColumn(name = "Supplier_Id",insertable=false,updatable=false)
private Supplier supplier;

@JoinColumns({
  @JoinColumn(name = "Supplier_Id",insertable=false,updatable=false),
  @JoinColumn(name = "Supplier_Contactperson_Id",insertable=false,updatable=false)
private SupplierContactperson supplierContactperson;

@Column(name="Supplier_Id")
private String supplier_id;
@Column (name = "Supplier_Contactperson_Id")
private String supplier_contact_Person_id;
```

and then in the setters
 for setSupplierContactPerson(contactPerson)

```
    supplierContactPerson = contactPerson;
if (contactPerson!=null){
       supplier_id = contactPerson.getSupplierID();
       supplier_contact_Person_id = contactPerson.getSupplierContactPersonID();
}
```

for setSupplier(supplier):

```
supplier = supplier;
 if (supplier != null){
   supplier_id = supplier.getId();
```

}

Comment: Didn't even think of that, but indeed this might work. I would probably add an `else` statement as well to unset the supplier/contactperson.

Answer (score 0):

To map only the id of ContactPersonSupplier has a problem: you could put a contact person from a supplier A and the supplier B and the database would not complain.
Since supplier is required, I'd try:
1. Put insert=false, update=false in the JoinColumn("supplier_id") of the contact person field, to avoid the complains from JPA.
2. modify (if still hadn't) setSupplierContactPerson() with

```
if (contactPerson != null){
    setSupplier(contactPerson.getSupplier());
} else {
    setSupplier(null);
}
```

Another option is to modify getSupplier() with

```
if (contactPerson != null){
    return contactPerson.getSupplier();
}
return supplier;
```

Comment: If I put `insertable=false, updatable=false` on that joincolumn, is complains as well, with: `Mixing insertable and non insertable columns in a property is not allowed: Article.supplierContactperson`, probably because it needs to have both columns inside a `@JoinColumns` to have the same "state". However, if I put it on both columns, I suppose I'm not able to save anymore.

Comment: You'd have to put them in the Supplier field, but since that is the mandatory and the other's not, it won't solve your problem. If you use only the contactPersonId and do the modification to the getter you'll get the behaviour you look for, but it'd still be possible to modify the data directly in the database and make inconsistencies. However, is the best approach I can think of